# How to hide/unhide a file from 'ls -a' in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, inode

I want to delete a file or folder by implementing my own system call such that after giving command 'ls -a' it must not be visible to me.

So basically I want to hide a file from commands like 'ls'or 'ls -a'. And then unhide it from the same.

It means I don't want it to completely delete it. Just hide it from user.

I am thinking it has to do some thing with

```
struct file_operations *f_op;
```

From where we can actually hide the file by manipulating 'readdir()'.

But I don't know how to manipulate it.

Any help?

P.S:- Linux Kernel version 3.5.x x86 64bit. I am doing changes in /linux/fs/namei.c

Comment: do you have to do it in kernel space ?

Comment: Sounds like you're writing a virus/rootkit?

Comment: @mux yes. I have to do it in kernel space.

Comment: @JimGarrison No. I want to implement a system call which can delete a file such that its not seen by ls -a. But at the same time I have to implement another system call which can undelete it. So cannot use unlink().

Comment: "rm -rf" hides files pretty well.

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to side-step the very deliberate security procedures put in place?

Comment: Don't do that. You want to violate an essential property of Unix.

Comment: Its a task given in my syllabus

Comment: No user would willingly install any software that did this. 'task given in my syllabus' - don't think so. Close voting.

Comment: @Martin James Problem Statement:- Now implement the undelete functionality in a truly transparent manner, i.e, when you delete a file, the trashed version of the deleted file should not be listed anywhere in the filesystem in any manner? For example, there should be no entry, such as .fname.trash, that gets listed anywhere in the filesystem with ls -a command.

Comment: You can write an alias to ls and in a script, in a function, ignore the -a option. That's all you should do, if you need to.

Comment: @askmish it it allowed in kernel space? I mean we can use alias in implementation of a system call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this - and even if there is, you shouldn't.

Instead, if you want to be able to "undelete" a file, you should have a folder somewhere on the file system (eg, ".Trash"), and instead of deleting the file using `unlink` or the like, just move the file into the trash directory.  On "undelete", just move the file back.  On "empty trash" or whatever, actually unlink the file from the hard drive.

This will have the effect of "hiding" the file from commands like `ls -a` because the file no longer exists in that folder; it's been moved to some Trash folder or Recycling Bin somewhere else on the hard drive.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you tell me then what is this : I mean is this on same path? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444995/Driver-to-hide-files-in-Linux-OS#

Comment: @SRJ - me pisses myself laughing. As soon as I saw a link to CodeProject I suspected who the article's author would be. I was not incorrect. Have a look at their other system-programming articles - all they ever seem to publish are hacky/back-door methods for effing-with things that the os should maintain exclusive rights to. For reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/Apriorit-Inc#articles

Comment: @SRJ: the article you linked to is, in my opinion, bad programming practice and should NEVER be used.  It is, per se, a hack.  It violates security principles and undermines good faith efforts of general computing.  Please never implement such a program, nor pursue such programming tactics.